# Seeing message in logs: "app:theme is deprecated"?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

Ever since upgrading to the latest appcompat library, I'm seeing a message in my logs from ViewUtils.

`app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.`

I'm using `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` as my theme parent.

Comment: the warning is not complaining about the theme itself, but about the `app` keyword. You should start using `android` in place of `app`

Comment: are you using ToolBar?

Comment: Yes, I am using Toolbar.

Comment: look in your layout which contains the Toolbar and look for `app:`, replace it with `android:`

Comment: See here for an official info: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Replace `app:theme` to `android:theme` but you can have a situation when you are not using `app:theme`. Check your layout, especially toolbar layout. In my case, I didn't have `app:theme` in my layout files. Then take a look at my situation:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:styled="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    styled:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarDarkPopup"
    styled:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay" />
```

And I've changed this layout to:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay" />
```

Now I don't see the warning.

Take a look also here:
https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/

Great explanation by Chris Banes

Comment: and what about 'popupTheme'? should we also use 'android' instead of 'styled'?

Comment: @BamsBamx No, you keep using styled:popupTheme, styled:contentInsetStart, etc. (as long as you're using the support library Toolbar). These are styleable attributes declared by the support library.

Comment: But this solutions works with every version of Android or there is any version which don't accept the use of andoid:teme?

Comment: @PauArlandisMartinez this has a bit more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279615/what-is-the-difference-b-w-apptheme-androidtheme-in-android-programming

Answer (score 19):

I had another case where this occurred when my `Toolbar` was styled in styles.xml. It looked like this:

```
<style name="AppActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/ng_blue</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppActionBar</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
</style>
```

Change `name="theme"` to `name="android:theme"` and it fixed the problem.

Comment: that was the place my search for `:theme` did not find as I just did not think about this location...

Answer (score 16):

Check your layout.

You are using a `Toolbar` where you have defined `app:theme.`

Now with the support 22.1 `app:theme` is deprecated. You should use `android:theme`

Check [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you see a code block like the following in the styles file ;

```
<item name="theme">@style/MyToolbarTheme</item>
```

Replace it.

```
<item name="android:theme">@style/MyToolbarTheme</item>
```