# Edittext color is white in appcompat 22.2

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-appcompat

**EDIT 2 :** This is happening because of the line

`<item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>`

in `styles.xml`. I'm using this to display light color (white) texts and back home button in `ToolBar`. If i change this to  `<item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>` then `EditText` is working as expected but my `ToolBar` text and back home button colors are changes to dark (black).

As I'm using dark colored `ToolBar` I would like to show the text and back home button in light (white) color.

I tried using `<item name="android:theme">...</item>` instead of `<item name="theme">...</item>` But nothing helped me, The toolbar text and back button still remains dark color! Any one figured out? Help me!

**ACTUAL QUESTION :**

In an `appcompat-v7:22.2.0` I used an `EditText`. An I'm using following theme for an `Activity`

```
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myPrimaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/myWindowBackground</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#0000AA</item>
</style>
```

But the color of an `EditText` is coming in white color. Bottom line, hint and text all are in white. I heard there is a bug in `AppCompat` But how to resolve this?

**EDIT 1 :** Adding more information

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marintopforelements"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/templatePaddingTop">

          <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/emailresponse"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/examtextdiff"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/inboxTabTextSize"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

colors.xml

```
<color name="myPrimaryColor">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="myPrimaryDarkColor">#FF304081</color>
<color name="myAccentColor">#3F51B5</color>
```

So previously when I was using `AppCompat-V7:21` It was coming like below image[image]

But after upgrading to `AppCompat-V7:22.2.0` Its like below image
[image]

So if it focused its coming like below image
[image]

Only that cursor line is in given accent color. But the hint and text are always in white! And this is happening even in both `EditText` and `AppCompatEditText` Hope this helps

Comment: Please add more details:
1) Your colour resource values e.g. what is the value of "myAccentColor"?
2) The XML Code of the Activity where the EditText is.

Comment: you mean background color of edittext, hint and text are all in white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Okie, I fixed it!**

What I was doing was, I want to display `ToolBar` content in white color as my ToolBar is dark so I used this line

`<item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>` in `styles.xml`

This was working fine with `appcompat-v7:21.+`.

But in `appcompat-v7:22.2.0` as the `app:theme` was depreciated (mentioned by @Guillaume Imbert in his answer).

So here was the confusion. I didn't use 'app:theme` any where in my project but it still keep showing me warning. So again I googled and found the this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854318/seeing-message-in-logs-apptheme-is-deprecated).

Which leads me to following [blog by Chris Banes](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) clearly explained about it.

Now I removed `<item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>` from `styles.xml`. So my `ToolBar` content is dark (Black).

Finally adding `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` in my `ToolBar` did the trick, So my toolbar code looks like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_size_x2"
    android:background="@color/myPrimaryColor"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

So this may help someone.

Thanks for giving me the good lead, both @reVerse and @Guillaume Imbert. Without your answers I would not able to fix this. Thanks a Lot :)

Comment: It helped me today. Thank a lot @Kevin I had been struggling with this same issue for a week. finally I found this post. Thanks a ton :-*

Comment: Ha ha! I'm happy that it helped you :) @Aksha

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you to create a theme/style only for your `EditText`. `Appcompat`uses by default the `android:textColorSecondary` as the color for the bottom line of the EditText though you haven't defined this in your Theme so it's hard to tell why your bottom line, text and hint is colored in white.

Here's an example for a separate Theme for EditText's

```
<style name="ThemeEditTextLight">
    <!-- bottom line color -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#000000</item>
    <!-- text color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <!-- hint text color -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#BDBDBD</item>
</style>
```

And then simply set the Theme to your EditText:

```
 <EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="My hint"
     android:theme="@style/ThemeEditTextLight" />
```

This approach gives you much more control over the coloring of your EditTexts.

Comment: This is like just applying theme to individual `EditText`. But my question is why I should do it! Is there any other way to do this? And `colorControlNormal` is working. But `android:textColor` and `android:textColorHint` is not working. Still the hint and text color are white. I updated my question kindly check again.

Comment: @KevinChris So when you're using this approach your textColor and textColorHint are still white?

Comment: Yes @reVerse. They are still white but the background changed to black

Comment: Hey @reVerse, any idea why its happening?

Comment: @KevinChris I've just created a project and used your code - unfortunately I can't reproduce the error you're facing. With the exact same code my `EditText` line is colored in teal and the textColor is black. (default colors). So most likely the error is coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use EditText, and not the compat one. At runtime, the support library replaces the EditText with the appcompat one only if needed.

Regarding your problem, appcompat 22.2 introduces the use of **android:theme** instead of **app:theme**.
I think the item **theme** in your style was not applied with the previous version of appcompat, and it is now.

By the way, I don't know if using the **theme** item into a theme is a good practice.

Comment: I didn't where exactly I should be worried about the `android:theme` and `app:theme`? I mean in manifest? If so, in manifest I'm using `android:theme`! It will be helpful if you explain me bit more regarding this!

Comment: The one on your EditText

Comment: To be more precise, with AppCompat 22,2 you should not worry about it : app:theme is deprecated. and that's the thing imo : now
**<item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>** really applies

Comment: I got it. In `styles.xml` I'm using `<item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>` to show my `Toolbar` text in white color. That was causing problem. Now I'm gave `<item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>` edittext is coming as expected and working fine but the toolbar texts changes to black. And I'm using `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` to display back button. This also became black. But I want them in white as I use dark color for ToolBar. What I suppose to do now?

Comment: As reverse said, use a style attribute on your EditText directly.

Comment: No If I do that also I was facing an issue, which I already mentioned in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81938/discussion-between-kevin-chris-and-guillaume-imbert).