# app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead

Tags: android, logging, android-studio, themes, warnings

I'm logging this warning:

`I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.`

The curious thing is that I've used the `Find in all project` tool of `Android Studio` and it haven't found any ocurrence with `app:theme`.

I think it can be because I'm using the `it.neokree.materialnavigationdrawer` and it can have `app:theme` inside, but anyway, is there any way to disable this warning? Anyone has idea if it could be for another reason?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Toolbar from the Support Library?

Comment: If `it.neokree.materialnavigationdrawer` uses it yes

Comment: Try exploring the Inspection tab in the Preferences of the IDE. In Eclipse, you can right-click on a warning to ignore it in the future. I suspect AS has something similar.

Comment: I'm not talking about IDE warnings, I mean warnings in running time, I find this warnings in the logs

Comment: I dont think you can. As long as your code raise the warning, it will show up in the log.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might have a style that contains an element like this:

```
<item name="theme">@style/TextInputTheme</item>
```

Replace with:

```
<item name="android:theme">@style/TextInputTheme</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Seeing message in logs: "app:theme is deprecated"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854318/seeing-message-in-logs-apptheme-is-deprecated) change from

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
```

to

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
```