# app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead android

Tags: android, xml, android-theme

I get some problem , I get error

> I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to
>   using android:theme instead.

but my xml is not use `app:theme`

and my styles.xml is have

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_orange</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_orange</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_orange</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

I don't know about error , How to fix it

Comment: Check your layout resources for occurrences of `app:theme`.

Comment: My xml is not use

Comment: Did you try searching your entire project? If not, are you using anything like <item name="theme">? Try changing it to name="android:theme"

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854318/seeing-message-in-logs-apptheme-is-deprecated