# What is the difference b/w app:theme & android:theme in Android Programming

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox, themes

I have seen this that some people write

```
app:theme="@style/xyz"
```

& on the other hand some write

```
android:theme="@style/xyz"
```

What is the difference b/w these 2 codes?

Answer (score 4):

`app` and `android` are actually namespaces. You can think of them in the same way as `packages` in java.
`android` namespace contains attributes from default views where as `app` refers to attributes from your app's namespace such as from custom views.

So when you write `android:theme`, it will use theme attribute which is part of default view such as a TextView(which is part of Android). Now when you use `app:theme` this means you are talking about a custom theme attribute and not the default one.
This can be useful when you are building a CustomView that extends another view and you also want to change how the `theme` attribute assigns values, For example, you might you want to build a custom view to add a shadow to a TextView and you want the shadow color to be provided in the theme.

Views from AppCompat library use `app:theme` to make their own version of `android:theme` to support older versions.

**TLDR;** Using `android:theme` uses View's default theme function whereas `app:theme` is for a custom theme function in custom views. If you are using an AppCompatView or a custom view, use `app:theme` when available, otherwise `android:theme`.

**What happens if I use `android:theme` instead of `app:theme` in MaterialDesign/AppCompat or any other custom view?**

If you do that, view's attributes that are available in all views will be customizable but any new attribute added by the custom view won't be customizable through theme.

Comment: Thanks Zohaib, you were quite helpful. You were to the point :)

Comment: @JustinJoseph No problem, please mark the answer as correct :)